# PDF text extractor

Tags: database, pdf, product, extractor

I need to upload into a database the information stored in advertising leaflets from the major retail chains (eg Carrefour, Lidl etc).

The quickest solution I've found is:

1. I download the PDF from the main site
2. I start a program called pic2filex that immediately saves images from clipboard
3. with the snapshot tool clipping all the various articles
4. launch a procedure that loads the images in the database and for each insert product name and price

Are there any faster methods?

Comment: Are you using OCR to grab product names and prices? On product leaflets, which I think are often quite noisy, this will be subject to a lot of error and manual correction.

Comment: I exclued to use OCR as i think I will spend more time to identify article name from all the text (as usually there are description too) and olso I have to join/save name + image (and price)

Comment: OK, bear in mind text extraction is also hard, since glyphs may be placed individually, or in groups, or rotated etc - working out what constitutes a line of text, and what lines constitute a block, is a non-trivial problem. Be sure to use existing libraries for this, since writing it will be very time-consuming.